# SQL Server Query Performance Test

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have 2 severs which have SQL server installed and the exact same database. The database has a store procedure which on Server A takes 35 minutes but on server B tables 9 hours. The procedure mainly updates a few tables but the data is the exact same so I don't understand why the time difference is so huge

Can someone advise me a dummy query which I can run on both servers (not relating to current data) to compare the performance. e.g. inserting 5 million rows and then update them all.

Just for information, the server B spec is a higher spec, the indexing is the same on the relevant tables, there is no blocking while server B SP is executing

Comment: 35 minutes is also a lot of time... perhaps the stored procedure is written badly and can be improved?

Comment: well 9 hours is worse. 35 is acceptable I guess

Comment: Is there a difference in the sql server version? the execution plan?

Comment: It could be any number of things, have you run a trace to find the slow queries?  Once you do that you can get an execution plan from both servers to compare.  Also check `@@VERSION` on both servers, and check the compatibilty levels.

Comment: Upload the execution plans of the fast and slow executions to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. That will help narrow down the cause to different plans versus other factors.

Comment: ok will do as soon as the server is free. thanks :)

Comment: It's been three hours, have you not been able to run your query again yet?

Comment: Sorry the below with recompile suggestion worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a alot of possibilities, but if the data and hardware ought to be similar in the two environments, then perhaps its [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) going on?

Basically it means that the first time the procedure is run, a plan is made with the current parameters, and this plan is saved with the procedure. The next time you run the procedure it reuses the old plan, which might be very bad for the new parameter.

You can try adding "WITH RECOMPILE" to see if that drastically changes the performance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE <procedure>
<Parameters>
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
```

Comment: Thanks. only thing is I moved the exactly same procedure from server A to B. no new parameters were added and nor was the procedure modified

Comment: Its the same code, but like I said, when you call the proc the first time, it saves the plan, look at the link to Brent Ozar for a better explanation:https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/